# Find the last element (digit) on each line and sum all that are even python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi there Stack Overflow!

I'm trying to solve an assignment we got in my Python class today. I'm not super familiar with python yet so I could really need some tips.

The task is to:
Find the last element (digit) on each line, if there are any, and sum all
that are even.

I have started to do something like this:

```
result = 0
counter = 0
handle = open('httpd-access.txt')
for line in handle:
    line = line.strip()
    #print (line)
    if line[:-1].isdigit():
        print(line[:-1].isdigit())
        digitFirst = int(line[counter].isdigit())
        if digitFirst % 2 == 0:
            print("second")
            result += digitFirst
    else:
        print("else")


    ANSWER = result
```

But this code doesnt work for me, I don't get any data in result.
What is it that i'm missing? Think one problem is that I'm not going through the line element by element, just the whole line.

Here is an example of how I line in the file can look:

```
37.58.100.166--[02/Jul/2014:16:29:23 +0200]"GET/kod-exempel/source.php?dir=codeigniter/user_guide_src/source/_themes/eldocs/static/asset HTTP/1.1"200867
```

So the thing I want to retrieve is the 7. And then I want to do a check if the seven is a even or odd number. If it's even, I save it in the a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't even bother with the `isdigit`. Go ahead and try the conversion to `int` and catch the exception if it fails.

```
result = 0
with open('httpd-access.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            i = int(line.strip()[-1:])

            if(i % 2 == 0):
                result += i

        except ValueError:
            pass

print('result = %d' % result)
```

Comment: That did the trick!
Just curious how it works dough so I can understand it.
You walk through the line in the foor loop. 
With the first line in the try, you retrieve the last digit, but what happends there if it would be not a int you retieve? Would it go to the except part then?

Comment: yes if the conversion fails it throws a `ValueError` exception. Which is caught and the code carries on after the try block. `pass` effectively does nothing. It just has to be there to satisfy the indentation requirement. You could also put a `continue` there if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

`isdigit()` return `True` or `False`, which is assigned to `digitFirst` (try print it!).
`True` and `False` are evaluated as 0 and 1 (respectively) in math operations.
So, it always pass the `if digitFirst % 2 == 0` when `digitFirst` is `0`, which means `0` always gets added to `result`.

Also, notice that `counter` is always 0 during the `for` loop and gets raised to 1 only after it, which means you are always working with the **first** letter of every line.

The purpose of `counter`is unclear as it only used as "the index of the letter you get" each line.

Comment: Ah okay, will move the counter inside the loop then :)
that why maybe I get nothing when I try to print our stuff and always get in my else in my code below:

http://pastebin.com/LDBwsrTa

Comment: Okay, so I can use isdigit() to see if it is a digit, but how do I actually retrieve the int after that? I guess I save the index position and then us that or?

Comment: You can access letters in string easily, as it is iterable. The first element can be accessed with `line[0]` while the last one with `line[-1]`.

Comment: @PaulRooney, okay just thought it would just be easier to show a pastebin that was related to the answer I got from galah92.
Should I then rephrase the question?

Comment: @galah92 ok. Let me see if I get this right now.
Fist I use my foor loop to read each line at a time. I also strip the line to remove unnecessary stuff.
Then I use my first if to check if anything in the line is a digit. I'm I doing that if-part correctly? Not sure if it's suppose to look like that.

And you say that isdigit() return a bool, true or false. So I have to convert that to an int() before I can use my modolus expression on it?

Comment: No. The thing is that in your first if you are asking for the element in `line` whose index is `counter` (and this should always be `-1` as you are looking for the last element in each line. Then you check if it is a digit, which in turn return `bool` which gets assigned.

Answer (score 1):

```
result = []
with open('https-access.txt') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        l = line.strip()
        if l[-1].isdigit():
            if int(l[-1]) % 2 == 0:
                result.append(int(l[-1]))
ANSWER = sum(result)
```

How does your file look? You want to calculate the last digit on each line if it's even number. In your code "line[counter]" will catch the first index of each line.

For example if data in file is as follows:

```
some_data 2
```

since counter is set to 0, therefore line['counter'] in your code will always check the first index which will be 's' in the example above.

If you can post a few lines from the file that you will be opening, I may be able to suggest something.

Comment: I updated the question with some line of code in the file that I'm trying to retrieve.

When I try your example I get an error saying "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'"

Comment: That's coz my example is appending str to list and not int. I've edited the example.